# Resources for first-order and second-order monadic logics with a model-checking objective

Tags: graph-algorithms, lo.logic, model-checking, first-order-logic

What are some good books and surveys for learning about first-order logic and monadic second-order logic?

I'm a graduate student in computer science with a focus on algorithms. For model-checking on graphs, I need to be familiar with the FO and MSO logics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what precisely do you want to learn. A good reference is the finite model theory book by Libkin. https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/fmt/fmt.pdf (chapters 2 and 7).

If you want more specific references, please be more precise with your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First, I would like to become familiar with the definitions and theorems of FO and MSO, although not on an advanced level. Furthermore, I am interested in knowing what problems and properties in graph theory are expressed and cannot be expressed by FO and MSO.

Comment: Ok, so I think that the first two chapters would be ok of Libkin's book will be ok (+ the chapter about MSO). Otherwise, you can also go through the following undergrad book: Mathematical Logic, 2nd Edition (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics) https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Logic-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387942580

Comment: Thanks! It seems like a great book. The book "Graph Structure and Monadic Second-Orderer Logic" by Courcelle and Engelfriet was also recommended by a friend.

Comment: Yes, but this is a way more advanced than the ones that I told you (say,  undergrad level vs PHD student / researcher level).